# Update the timezone on DST when using ScheduledExecutorService scheduled tasks in Android

Tags: java, android, timezone, dst, scheduledexecutorservice

I am creating an Android API16 application to schedule a periodic task.

I got the expected result by using ScheduledExecutorService however there is a particular case where the scheduled task will be 1h late or 1h early. If I schedule it in winter then I will use GMT+1 but it will be GMT+2 if the task is scheduled on summer.

How can I "auto-update" the timezone of any scheduled task before it mistakes the execution?

Comment: That’s not trivial. If you are using `scheduleAtFixedRate`, you are getting a fixed rate as the method name says, and if you set that rate to 24 hours, you are getting 24 hours no matter if a day is occasionally 23 or 25 hours because of summer time (DST). Maybe it’s easier to schedule each instance of the task separately at the time you want. You may also want to look into a third party scheduler such as Quartz.